# Old inputs on Laravel FormBuilder keeps appearing even though i set new values

Tags: php, session, laravel, formbuilder

I got a weird behaviour with the 'old value' feature from FormBuilder in Laravel 5.1.

On my blade template I use a simple text input:

```
{!! Form::open([ 'url' => route('album-photo'), 'method' => 'POST' ]) !!}

     {!! Form::text('album_id', $album_id) !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

On my controller I show the view:

```
$album_id = 1;
return view( $name_view, compact( 'album_id' ) );
```

The problem is that, even though I change the album_id value on my controller, the form builder on my view will keep printing the first value.

While if I use the normal html tag:

```
<input type="text" name="album_id" value="{{ $album_id }}" />
```

it will print the updated value.

So it looks like the FormBuilder class is getting the value from the old session and it can't manage the refreshing of the value.

Is there a way to fix it and keep using the FormBuilder methods instead of plain html?

Comment: could you show us the rest of the code? for example the form construction (are you using open or model)

Comment: @AbstractChaos updated. I'm using the open method

Comment: probably this happens caching the views, check with the old value then go to `app/storage/views` and delete the all files and change value to a new one and test again, if its getting correct value then the issue is in cache, if your again getting the old  value then there may be a other case.